# Не открываются ссылки на странице при подключении jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css, вёрстка

Верстаю простой сайт на HTML и CSS. Все работает, но при подключении скрипта:

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  $('#ddmenu li').hover(function () {
     clearTimeout($.data(this,'timer'));
     $('ul',this).stop(true,true).slideDown(200);
  }, function () {
    $.data(this,'timer', setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
      $('ul',this).stop(true,true).slideUp(200);
    }, this), 100));
  });

});
</script>
```

---

Все ссылки на странице перестают работать, хотя указатель мыши отображает их как ссылки, но не открывает. Только по нажатии правой кнопкой мыши -> "открыть в новой вкладке"
В чем может быть проблема? Завтра дедлайн, уже 3 дня думаю над проблемой, надеюсь на помощь.

Answer (score 4):

Так вы сами [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) сделали... Это значит, что ссылки не будут обрабатываться обычным способом.

Answer (score 0):

Как уже писали, вот эта часть скрипта не дает браузеру обрабатывать ссылки

```
  $('a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

Если ее убрать, то всё заработает.